# "Object is required"

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to do mathematical operation of adding 3 columns (Y, AA and AB).

But each time running the code, it displays error message of

> object is required

```vb
Sub QCValue()

    Dim Number1 As Range
    Dim Number2 As Range
    Dim Number3 As Range

    Set Number1 = Sheets("RawData").Range("Y2:Y" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set Number2 = Sheets("RawData").Range("AA2:AA" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set Number3 = Sheets("RawData").Range("AB2:AB" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Sheets("RawData").Range("AJ2:AJ" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = Number1 + Number2 + Number3

End Sub
```

Kindly please assist me in troubleshooting.

Comment: Your approach seems a bit off, I don't think you can sum up Ranges like this. Try the below code, It should work. Basically it's a loop summing Values in the Column `AJ`.

Answer (score 1):

You have work a loop for that. Like this below should do the job.

```
Sub QCValue()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("RawData").Range("AJ" & i).Value = Sheets("RawData").Range("Y" & i).Value + Sheets("RawData").Range("AA" & i).Value + Sheets("RawData").Range("AB" & i).Value

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Accept this as answer :)

Comment: my knowledge is totally zero in this VBA, still catching, if you may, what was wrong in my original script?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, In your original code you were trying to add the Ranges itself rather than their values.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand correctly you could use:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub QCValue()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")

        'Find Last rows of Columns Y
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-11],RC[-9],RC[-8])"

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but it doesnt work. 
I wish to add colum Y2 + AA2 + AB2 , later it continues to do the same operation for Y3+ AA3 + AB3  etc till Yn + AAn + ABn